# Dojo Tabs as Custom Widgets

Tags: dojo, widget

I've created a number of widgets that are loaded as tab panes in a tabcontainer. Everything seems to work well, except I'm getting different results when using my custom widgets vs. creating everything in markup (tab content isn't taking up the whole page, 3rd party widgets aren't behaving properly, etc). This all leads me to think that I might not be creating my widgets correctly. The trick seems to be that they are not interpreted as contentpanes.

I am using dojo 1.3.2.

The following markup, for example, works great:

```
<body class="soria" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <!-- Container for whole page -->
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" id="borderContainer" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        <!-- Header container -->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">
            Title
        </div>
        <!-- Left side -->
        <!--<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" id="addressContainer" splitter="true" style="width:100%; background-color: #F0F8FF;">-->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" id="addressContainer" splitter="true">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <!-- address -->
                <span id="addressInstructions">Address Contents</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="tabs" region="center" tabPosition="top">
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="tab1" title="map">
                <p>Change map to:</p>
                <div id="divMapList"></div>
                <div style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    <div id="divMap" dojoAttachPoint="divMap" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #000;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="tab2" title="other">
                Some text in here.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Looking at the resulting HTML code, I can see that the tab itself has the following class: "dijitContentPane dijitTabPane dijitTabContainerTop-child dijitTabContainerTop-dijitContentPane dijitVisible".

Below is the HTML of one of my custom widgets:

```
<div>
    <div style="text-align: center; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <div>${i18nStrings.mapChangeMap}:</div>
        <div dojoAttachPoint="divMapSelection"></div>
        <div style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
            <div id="divMap" dojoAttachPoint="divMap" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #000;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is part of the custom widget JS (I can provide more code if necessary):

```
dojo.declare("xxxx.Widget.Map", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],
{
    //Specify the path of the HTML file that sets the look of the widget
    templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl("xxxx", "widget/templates/Map.html"),

    //The strings used to populate standard text. Populated in postMixInProperties
    i18nStrings: null,

    //The widget's root div identifier. Value overwritten in postMixInProperties
    id:"tabMap",

    //The tab's title. Value overwritten in postMixInProperties
    title: "",

    //True to activate the tab. False otherwise.
    activate: false,

    //The map & current layer
    map: null,
    currentLayer: null,

    //Sets up some basic properties
    postMixInProperties: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        var _1 = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("dijit", "loading", this.lang);
        this.loadingMessage = dojo.string.substitute(this.loadingMessage, _1);
        this.errorMessage = dojo.string.substitute(this.errorMessage, _1);
        if (!this.href && this.srcNodeRef && this.srcNodeRef.innerHTML) {
            this.isLoaded = true;
        }
        this.i18nStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("IndyVIP","applicationStrings");
        this.title = this.i18nStrings.mapTabTitle;
    },
</div>
```

I am adding the widget to the container by creating the widget, then adding it as a child to the tabcontainer.

This results in the following class assigned to my tab: "dijitTabPane dijitTabContainerTop-child dijitVisible".

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Emmster

UPDATE:
I have decided to try inheriting from dijit.layout.ContentPane & dijit._Templated. I am still having problems with that though, the main one being that if I add my widget to a TabContainer, I get the error "node is null" on line 4467 of dojo.js.uncompressed.js, but the tab seems to work just fine IF it's the active tab starting out. If I add the widget to a page that only contains the widget, it works fine without errors.

See the code below that gives me the expected results, but causes that one "node is null" error.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            useXDomain: true,
            debugAtAllCosts: true,
            baseUrl: './',
            modulePaths: {IndyVIP: 'js'}
        };
    </script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/1.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=1.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("IndyVIP.Widget.Map");
        dojo.addOnLoad(init);
        function init() {
            var tab = new IndyVIP.Widget.Map({title: 'Map'});
            var tabContainer = dijit.byId('tabs');
            tabContainer.addChild(tab);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="soria" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <!-- Container for whole page -->
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" id="borderContainer" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        <!-- Header container -->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">
            Title
        </div>
        <!-- Left side -->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" id="addressContainer" splitter="true">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <!-- address -->
                <span id="addressInstructions">Address Contents</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs-->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="tabs" region="center" tabPosition="top">
            <!-- uncommenting the following results in map not acting the way it should -->
            <!--
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="tab2" title="other">
                Some text in here.
            </div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Map.js:

```
dojo.provide("IndyVIP.Widget.Map");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");

dojo.declare("IndyVIP.Widget.Map", [dijit.layout.ContentPane, dijit._Templated],
{
    map: null,

    //Specify the path of the HTML file that sets the look of the widget
    templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl("IndyVIP", "widget/templates/Map.html"),

    //The tab's title. Value overwritten in postMixInProperties
    title: "",

    widgetsInTemplate: true,

    startup: function() {
        this.map = new esri.Map('divMap');
        dojo.connect(this.map, 'onLayerAdd', this, this.onLayerAdd);
        var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer');
        this.map.addLayer(layer);
    },

    onLayerAdd: function() {
        //Create symbol
        var lineColor = new dojo.Color('black');
        var lineSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,lineColor,1);
        var pointColor = new dojo.Color('red');
        var pointSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,12,lineSymbol,pointColor);

        //Create point
        var x = 4.92;
        var y = 50.625;
        var point = new esri.geometry.Point(x,y,this.map.spatialReference);

        //Create template
        var template = new esri.InfoTemplate('A title','Some content');

        //Create graphic
        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point,pointSymbol,null,template);

        //Add graphic to map
        this.map.graphics.clear();
        this.map.graphics.add(graphic);
    }

});
```

And finally, here's the widget's HTML template:

```
<div>
    <div id="divMap" dojoAttachPoint="divMap" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #000;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
</div>
```

I very much appreciate all of your suggestions so far. I feel like I am missing something elementary, but I can't quite figure it out.

Emmster

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem is that your content not filling the content pane? What do you mean when you say "3rd party widgets aren't behaving properly"?

Comment: That's part of the problem, yes. The 3rd party widget I'm using is ESRI's JavaScript API (http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/index.cfm?fa=home). The map I'm adding is not behaving as it should.

Comment: I started playing with my custom widgets yesterday and instead of inheriting from [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], I'm now trying to inherit from [dijit.layout.ContentPane, dijit._Templated]. I'm getting errors with that as well, but I just started playing with that option.

Comment: Have you tried testing your widget on a page independent of the container?  See if you can get it to appear in a fixed-size div, like this:

<div style="width: 400px; height: 250px;>
  <div dojoType="your.widget.Here" id="mywidget"></div>
</div>

You can then poke around your object in the firebug console using dijit.byId('mywidget').  I have found this helps considerably in debugging.  If your widget does work as expected, then try resizing the containing div at runtime and see how your widget responds.  Your widget may be created while inside a hidden or 0 height container.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to use DOM id attributes anywhere in your widget markup template (like id="divMap").  Creating multiple instances of your widget will result in DOM nodes with the same id; the dojoAttachPoint is all you should need.

Comment: Curious if the problem comes from the nature of TabContainer children (non-selected) being hidden with display:none and the map not being able to intiialize/render at that state. Does the problem go away if the tab has selected=true or otherwise in a visible state at the time of instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was having when inheriting from dijit.layout.ContentPane was that my top div in my widget template did not specify dojoAttachPoint="containerNode". Doing this took care of the "node is null" error I was getting.
I am still having issues with the map not behaving properly, but this seems related to the tab not being visible initially as dante hinted.

UPDATE:
The other error I was having (the map not acting as it should) was due to the widget's template HTML having items above the map in the widget HTML as in my first example above (map.html). In the second example I provided, I took that extra stuff out, and that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting from the ContentPane and having dojoAttachPoint="containerNode" on the root node seems to be mandatory for the tabs. This helped me to resolve a similar issue.